# How to add a dynamic reference in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, cross-reference

I have a passage of text that references an image further down. If the image is on the same page as the passage, I want the passage to include the string "as pictured below". If the image is pushed onto the next page, I want it to say "as pictured on the next page".

I vaguely recall Word supporting dynamic in-text references like that, but after searching for it for a while I came up empty.

(Word for Mac version 16.46)

Answer (score 2):

Based on my test, it seems that you could use if field and Reference filed to get the following result.

On my test environment, I create a Caption as "Picture 2", then I use the field `{ If {PAGEREF _Ref76656520 \h } > { Page } "as { Ref _Ref76656520 } on the next page" "as { Ref _Ref76656520 \h } below"}`.

But it does not create a hyperlink.

Then the result would be like the following image.

[image]

Comment: Good answer! It is important to remember that the IF field will not automatically update when the location changes. That field must be updated. You might want to add something to that effect in your answer.